# Magento 2- Catalog categories product re-order is not getting updated on frontend

Tags: magento2

I am trying to re-order my products from my catalog categories, but it is not getting updated on the frontend immediately, sometimes it takes hours or days to get updated.

I tried verifying the settings from the Store view and clearing the cache.

I can see the updated order on the admin but not on the frontend.

So what changes needed to be made in order to update the product order on the frontend immediately?

Answer (score 0):

try Re index and check

```
bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am using Magento Cloud. So is there any way to do it from Admin?